# Why Context.Request.GetHttpContext() returns null inside Hub inheritor's method?

Tags: c#, signalr, owin

To access `IOwinContex` we need call `Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext();`

But `Context.Request.GetHttpContext()` returns `null`;
I have checked `Context.Request.Environment` dictionary. It does not contains `HttpContextBase` instance. Why is it so?

Configuration of self-hosted OWIN on Windows 7 application:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Owin;

//...

private void StartSerice()
{
    WebApp.Start("http://127.0.0.1:8080/", (app) =>
    {
      app.Map("/api", map =>
      {
        map.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration
        {
          EnableDetailedErrors = true
        });
      });

      app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
      {
        EnableDefaultFiles = true,
        FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./www"),
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false,
        RequestPath = new PathString("")
      });
    }
}
```

`AccountHub` class:

```cs
public class AccountHub : Hub
{
  public void TestMethod(string message)
  {
    HttpContextBase httpContextBase = Context.Request.GetHttpContext(); // is null

    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance use GlobalHost to get the hub and invoke your hub method?

Comment: @Pawel I'am trying to use hub for custom authorization inside connection.

Comment: @Pawel May be it's a bad idea. But I can't make auth work in 3 days. Can't understand how it should work with Mysql+SignalR.

Comment: I don't quite see how your question relates to authorization. If you have a question about authorization ask a question about authorization. You asked why `GetHttpContext()` returns null but did not show how the hub method is being invoked. Asking a different question in comments is not effective since comment size is limited.

Comment: @Pawel Well, my main problem is `GetHttpContext()` now. Why it returns `null`?

Comment: @Pawel Maybe I misunderstood the first comment. So, I do never use GlobalHost to get the hub.